# Reference to another JSON file in JSON file

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have response, that contain JSON file with array, which contains 2 type of data : simple String ("name") and href to another JSON file.

And if I get this first file with Retrofit, what is good move to get all the data from that href value?

```
{
"count": 357,
"next": "https://api.gwentapi.com/v0/cards/?limit=1\u0026offset=1",
"results": [{
    "href": "https://api.gwentapi.com/v0/cards/kW4_kj1UVoOPxxw4M_w_2A",
    "name": "Abaya"
}]
}
```

I presume that it is not that smart if I just use another 300+ retrofit calls.
Or it is just an example of bad json structure?

Comment: The structure seems to be optimized for the case where you don't need all of the sub-documents. This would for example be the case when it is used for a list view (just showing the name) and a separate detail view where you then fetch the details for exactly the one record you need.

Comment: @Henry Yes, i understand that. The problem is that i need data from this nested JSON :(

Comment: In this case there is no other way than to fetch them one by one. Unless the server provides another API to get all data in one go.